# Does || operator disable further concatenation?

Tags: javascript

I've got some code like this:

```
a = "string1" + b || c + "string2";
```

And it's working as intended except string2 is left off the end when it's run.

Is there a way to make this work with parentheses perhaps? Or maybe another method?

Edit: The idea was for the code to concatenate string1, result of b || c, and string2 together.

Comment: `with parentheses perhaps?` Did you try that?

Comment: That is parsed equivalently to `a = ("string1" + b) || (c + "string2");`. Did you really want that? If not, the code will need to - "with parentheses", or otherwise - give JS some hints of what *should* be done..

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Operator_precedence)

Comment: What do you expect to happen when that's run? Have you tried adding parentheses?

Comment: One thing I like about programming is that when you have a doubt such as this, you can try it in your favorite coding environment (for example, a browser console would do in this case). You should try things you think would "perhaps" work, sometimes, it's totally free!

Comment: I tried a = "string1" + (b || c) + "string2"; But that also failed to work.

Comment: If the left hand side of `||` evaluates as true, then there is no point evaluating the right hand side. So it won't. It's not clear what you expected it to do.

Comment: You should never try to put parentheses! Never! It will ruin your entire life.

Comment: @user3055938 What do you expect this code to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` has [higher precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Operator_precedence) than `||`. What this means is that your code effectively means this:

```
var temp1 = "string1" + b;
var temp2 = c + "string2";
a = temp1 || temp2;
```

If you want the string to start with `"string1"`, end with `"string2"`, and have either `b` or `c` in the middle, then you can wrap the `||` section in parentheses to ensure it's evaluated before the concatenation.

```
a = "string1" + (b || c) + "string2";
```

Example:

```js
function log(msg) {
  document.querySelector('pre').innerText += msg + '\n';
}

var a;
var b = false;
var c = "__C__";
a = "string1" + (b || c) + "string2";
log(a);

b = "__B__";
a = "string1" + (b || c) + "string2";
log(a);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for explanation. However I tried that solution before asking the question and it didn't work for me.

Comment: @user3055938 It should work. I just added an example that does exactly as you want. If your code doesn't work like this then there's something else going on.

Comment: @user3055938: What did you expect it to do? That did you expect *the result of `b||c`* to be?

Comment: You're right. It does work. It's because it's working it's throwing an error. I just assumed it was the cause of the error. Thanks.